# shell scripting grant command is not working in mysql

Tags: shell

I have created a shell script as given below.The aim is to create a database in a remote machine and give all privileges on that database for a specific user in remote machine.
The shell script is as follows.

> ssh root@10.3.2.0 'echo "db name :";
>   read db_name;
>   echo "db user :";
>   read db_user;
>   echo "user password:";
>   read password;
>   host=localhost;
>   sql1="create database $db_name;";
>   sql2="grant all on ${db_name}.* to ${db_user}@${host} identified by "${password}";";
>   sql3="${sql1}${sql2}";
>   mysql -u root -p -e "${sql3}";
>   '

And the output Iam getting is as foloows

> root@10.3.2.0's password: 
>   db name :
>   amblex
>   db user :
>   qbadmin
>   user password:
>   xxxx 
>   Enter password: xxxx
>   ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'qburst' 
> at line 1

What could be the mistake in my script.PLease help me to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772335/create-database-in-shell-script-convert-from-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of ...

```
sql2="grant all on ${db_name}.* to ${db_user}@${host} identified by "${password}";";
```

... try this ...

```
sql2="grant all on ${db_name}.* to ${db_user}@${host} identified by \"${password}\";";
```

Also you might want to consider using `expect`.