# How to create table after create database using shell_script in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, shell-exec, create-table

After solve the issue to create a database using shell_script in php, see this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30869086/how-to-create-a-mysql-database-using-shell-exec-php), I was trying to create tables inside the same shell_exec command.

I have these lines:

```
$sql="CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS dbtest; use dbtest; CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50),
reg_date TIMESTAMP
) ";

shell_exec("mysql -uroot -pmypasswrd  -e  \"$sql\" ");
```

This code only creates the database, but not creates the table. My question is how accomplish this task using shell_exec()? Is it possible to run a sql satatment that comes from a mysqldump using shell_exec()?

Comment: I couldn't find anything on this really, but see if this helps http://gotoanswer.com/?q=Create+tables+from+SQL+dump+generated+by+phpmyadmin+using+kohana

Comment: I though I saw somewhere that after -e we could use sql statements separeted by ;

Comment: I've never used that method before, so I thought I'd Google around for you to see if I could find anything related. Did the info on that page help you?

Comment: Hi Fred, you link gave new information, but didnt solve the problem. Thkns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This code only creates the database, but not creates the table. My question is how accomplish this task using shell_exec()?

The only one solution I can find for your problem is to write your whole SQL query in one line (without breaking it into several lines). It will affect the readability of your code, but your table will be created.

Comment: Yes, you are wright. I just run a script to delete "\n" to the end of the line (that is invisible) and it worked. I still have some issues because my sql script is 10k lines. But the main issue was "\n" that is not a sql command and stopped the shell_exec -e.